# NoSQL, DBRefs : MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, relationship, relation, nosql

How can I create a DBRef according to a given field by myself? For example, I have the UID field in the customer table, and I also have this UID field in the orders table, which will serve to reference the customer that this request belongs to, it's just not working very well, see:

```
> db.customers.findOne();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4ef4a61a90eec3e3c748263c"),
        "uid" : 1,
        "name" : "Andrey",
        "lastname" : "Knupp Vital"
}
> db.orders.findOne();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4ef4a66490eec3e3c748263d"),
        "oid" : 1,
        "uid" : 1,
        "price" : "149.90"
}
> db.orders.remove();
> order = { oid : 1 , price : 149.90 , uid : new DBRef ( 'customers' , 1 ) } ;
{
        "oid" : 1,
        "price" : 149.9,
        "uid" : {
                "$ref" : "customers",
                "$id" : 1
        }
}
> db.orders.save ( order ) ;
> order.uid.fetch();
null
> order.uid
{ "$ref" : "customers", "$id" : 1 }
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DBRef $id value must always be set to the value of the _id field of the referred document. You're not doing that in your example. Fixed version :

```
> db.customers.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4ef4a61a90eec3e3c748263c"),
        "uid" : 1,
        "name" : "Andrey",
        "lastname" : "Knupp Vital"
}
> db.orders.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4ef4a66490eec3e3c748263d"),
        "oid" : 1,
        "uid" : 1,
        "price" : "149.90"
}
> db.orders.remove()
> order = { oid : 1 , price : 149.90 , uid : new DBRef ( 'customers' , ObjectId("4ef4a61a90eec3e3c748263c") ) } ;
{
        "oid" : 1,
        "price" : 149.9,
        "uid" : {
                "$ref" : "customers",
                "$id" : ObjectId("4ef4a61a90eec3e3c748263c")
        }
}
> db.orders.save(order)
> order.uid.fetch()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4ef4a61a90eec3e3c748263c"),
        "uid" : 1,
        "name" : "Andrey",
        "lastname" : "Knupp Vital"
}
```

Comment: Is not deprecated, .fetch() ??

Comment: @arivero It might be. This answer is almost 2 years old ;) I have yet to run into any use cases where DBRefs are particularly practical though so I'd stick with simple _id values.

Answer (score 2):

I do it manually. Having an extra identifier field will likely end up causing problems down the road. In your order documents, create a 'customer_id field and set it to the _id of the customer. It's like create a SQL Foreign Key with the relational reference. I do it in PHP like this:

```
$customer = $this->mongo->db->customer->findOne(array("name" => $customer_name));
$customer_id = new MongoID($customer['_id']);
$order = Array(
            'customer_id' => $customer_id,
        ...
        );

$this->mongo->db->order->insert($order);
```